# Google Chart: AreaChart vAxis Gridlines is Not Drawing

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

As per title above, is there anyone know why? My code is as follows, and by the way, I am using the Google Chart Playground to testing out on it, http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#area_chart.  Please advise, thanks!

```
<html>
   <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Hour', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['0:00',  1000, 500],
      ['1:00',  1170, 604],
      ['2:00',  660, 302],
      ['3:00',  1030, 827],
      ['4:00', 1222, 86]
    ]);

    var options = {
      areaOpacity: 0.7,
      backgroundColor:{
        color: 'none',
        fill: 'none',
      },
      animation:{
        easing: 'inAndOut',
      },
      hAxis: {gridlines: {color: '#000000', count: 3}},
      vAxis: {gridlines: {color: '#DCDCDC', count: 5}},
      tooltipTextStyle: {color: '#444444', fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 12},
      focusTarget: 'category',         
      series: {
        0:{color: '#207795', lineWidth: 4, pointSize: 10},
        1:{color: '#464A54', lineWidth: 4, pointSize: 10},
      },
      legend: 'none',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get vertical gridlines you have to set hAxis gridlines (done) and change x-axis data type to a continuous data type. See [Customizing Axes/Terminology](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology) and area chart: Configuration Options: hAxis.gridlines description.

Instead of

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Hour', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  ['0:00',  1000, 500],
  ['1:00',  1170, 604],
  ['2:00',  660, 302],
  ['3:00',  1030, 827],
  ['4:00', 1222, 86]
]);
```

you have to provide for example:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Hour', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
  [0,  1000, 500],
  [1,  1170, 604],
  [2,  660, 302],
  [3,  1030, 827],
  [4,  1222, 86]
]);
```

Note hour data is not a string any more. And if you change  `count` value of `hAxis` to 5, you will get vertical line for each hour:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Code hasn't any error, you have missed `chart_div` in your markup..

```
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**See Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/LE7V3/

Comment: I don't see any vertical gridlines in your jsfiddle either. Do you?